# Table Left Join

Tags: sql, database, oracle, join

I'm currently trying to get an output from two tables that I want to join and it seems like I have a block in my mind on how to resolve this.

Table 1 has products with unique IDs.

```
ID | (other info)
-----------------
AA |
BB |
CC |
```

Table 2 has the unique ID of Table 1 as FK as well as a model number and a part-code that I would like to join onto Table 1. Table 2 has a multitude of other information resulting in the following possible constellation:

```
ID | FK | model number | part-code
-----------------------------------
01 | AA | model0001    | part923
02 | AA | model0001    |
03 | AA |              | part923
04 | BB | model0002    |
05 | BB |              | part876
06 | CC |              | part551
```

Information in Table 2 is therefore very scattered and not necessarily complete. I also do not want to assume that for a given FK the model number and the part-code remain the same across all entries (if there are multiple variants for a given FK, I only want one entry, even if it is at random).

The result I am trying to achieve is to get all the information I extract from Table 1, and it is given that there will always be a unique ID (=FK in Table 2), and add the model number and part-code, if existing, to the table without creating any duplicates. The example above should therefore give the following output.

```
ID | model number | part-code | (other info from table 1)
---------------------------------------------------------
AA | model0001    | part923   |
BB | model0002    | part876   |
CC |              | part551   |
```

I should also mention that Table 2 is extremely large (millions of entries) and I have no way to match the data except with the IDs from Table 1. This table is also quite big - an efficient way of approaching this is therefore necessary.
Thank you for your time in reading this and helping me understand how to approach this.
Best,
Jonas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, you need an OUTER JOIN to get all the records in `table1` with whatever matching records are in `table2`.

Getting only one record per hit from `table2` is tricky. This aggregating subquery will produce your desired output. Note that this solution can produce a permutation of `(model_number,part_code)` which does not exist in any single record in `table2` ; I guess it's okay  as that is what your sample result set shows for `BB`. The performance across "millions of entries" may be slow. But that is a (separate) tuning issue.

```
select t1.id
       , t2.model_number 
       , t2.part_code
       , t1.whatever
       , t1.blah
       , t1.etc
from table1 t1
left outer join ( select fk 
                         , max (model_number) as model_number
                         , max (part_code) as part_code
                  from table2 
                  group by fk ) t2
    on t1.id = t2.fk
order by t1.id
/
```

Comment: Thanks, this should have worked but the system killed the job while executing due to excessive use of resources. I'll try to find a way to improve upon this!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this SQL

```
SELECT t1.ID, t2.model_number, t2.part-code FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.FK
GROUP BY t1.ID
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: OP wants all information from Table 1, not just the ID. Does that provide them?

Comment: This is what I am currently doing (though slightly modified as I need additional information as Paul Karam mentioned). A simple left join with grouping does not work as I receive duplicate rows for instances in which I have multiple rows per FK in Table 2.